# Write TCL/ TK codes in visual studio 12.0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am new to TCL/ TK and want to write codes, which can be executed in visual studio 12.0. Is there any way i can add some plugin in visual studio, so that i am able to write TCL/ TK codes in VS 12.0?
I have ActiveState ActiveTCL 8.6.4.1 installed on my Windows machine.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I mostly use either Emacs or Eclipse (with DLTK plugins) for Tcl programming. I would be interested in answers to your question, even if just to tell others.

Comment: @DonalFellows But my requirement is to work in visual studio only.

Comment: Which is exactly why that wasn't an answer. Possible workaround perhaps (given that I didn't know you had a strong requirement otherwise) but not an answer.

Comment: Did you allready have a look at Eagle? http://eagle.to/

Comment: @eagle.to not really.